# Unattended-Upgrade::Origins-Pattern for repository without Origin, label etc

Tags: debian, unattended-upgrades

I'd like to use `unattendedupgrades` to keep Collabora Office updated on my Debian 10 Nextcloud server.

However, the [InRelease file for the repository](https://www.collaboraoffice.com/repos/CollaboraOnline/CODE-debian10/InRelease) doesn't contain any of the metadata I'd use in an `Unattended-Upgrade::Origins-Pattern` line - it's only got the file hashes, so all the this is all the `apt-cache policy` returns:

```
 500 https://www.collaboraoffice.com/repos/CollaboraOnline/CODE-debian10 ./ Packages
     release c=
```

How do I specify that I want this repo's packages to be automatically updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments in content of `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`:

> ```
> // Lines below have the format format is "keyword=value,...".  A
> // package will be upgraded only if the values in its metadata match
> // all the supplied keywords in a line.  (In other words, omitted
> // keywords are wild cards.) The keywords originate from the Release
> // file, but several aliases are accepted.  The accepted keywords are:
> //   a,archive,suite (eg, "stable")
> //   c,component     (eg, "main", "contrib", "non-free")
> //   l,label         (eg, "Debian", "Debian-Security")
> //   o,origin        (eg, "Debian", "Unofficial Multimedia Packages")
> //   n,codename      (eg, "jessie", "jessie-updates")
> //     site          (eg, "http.debian.net")
> ```

You can still distinguish this by *site* with the `site` keyword in the relevant setting by editing `50unattended-upgrades` and changing the `Unattended-Upgrade::Origins-Pattern` block like this:

```
Unattended-Upgrade::Origins-Pattern {
        "origin=Debian,codename=${distro_codename},label=Debian";
        "origin=Debian,codename=${distro_codename},label=Debian-Security";
        "site=www.collaboraoffice.com";
}
```